# How can we verify DOM elements in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, automation, element

Suppose some elements change in UI and then how can we verify our elements ?

Is there any logic or code to verify our elements regular in Website ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to check all of your elements. If you use some of them in tests and the tests start failing then you know that your elements are changed. Another way is to get the whole HTML of the page and assert it every time but this is not the best practice, and I don't recommend it.